# How to change my text status to button

Tags: php, html, css

Hello guys i want to make some changes but i dont know how :/

This is my code

http://pastebin.com/9c6caFnP

(sorry for the likn the system cant get my code and i see error when i add the code)

I want this if my status is online i want the Button one (the green one)
If the status is offline i want the second button (the gray one)
+ i want if i am offline the button to be disabled (last codes are for buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$online_state` has 3 states: `online`, `in-game` and `offline`, using [if-else](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.elseif.php) will solve the problem in a very simple way:

```
if($online_state == 'online')
    echo '<a href="#" class="myButton">BOT 1# ONLINE</a>';
else if($online_state == 'offline')
    echo '<a href="#" class="myButton2">BOT 1# OFFLINE</a>';
```

Comment: Doesnt work .... maybe i make mistake can you repair this in my code ? I mean make changes on my code with ur code

Comment: If you don't know how to do this on your own you should probably consider to learn PHP and HTML basiscs first. Stackoverflow is not a website for getting work done for you. It is a site for Questions and answers. Please have a look at the [SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first (you'll be rawarded with a bronze badge afterwards).

Comment: I put this in my code i didnt get any answer from the code ... -_-
http://pastebin.com/7qAEA2GW this is my new code still doesnt work